# javascript scope issue in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope

In code below, I expect variable counter to incement by 1 on each repetition, but it remains zero.

```
var count = 0;
var marqueeText = new Array("Some text goes here",
                            "A bit more verbose text goes here.",
                            "Some more verbose <a href='xxx'>text</a> goes <a href='xxx'>here</a> with some <a href='xxx'>links</a>."
                            );

function fnShowMarquee(count){  
// console.log(count + "-" + marqueeText.length );
        if (count > marqueeText.length){
            count = 0;      
        }
        else{           
            count++;
        }
        $('#marquee_box span').html(marqueeText[count]);

            // do some stuff, then wait 4 seconds and call function again

        setTimeout ("fnShowMarquee(count)", 4000);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    fnShowMarquee(0);
});
```

Comment: rats... gtg but hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/62k5j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using `count` explicitly:

```
setTimeout (function() { fnShowMarquee(count); }, 4000);
```

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge Why bother passing it in at all? It's already a global.

Comment: why not `setTimeout(function(){fnShowMarquee(count);}, 4000)` -- no need for creating a string

Comment: @vol7ron - because it can be just:`setTimeout(fnShowMarquee, 4000)` since *count* is global.

Comment: @RobG: that's if *count* is global.  This is only a snippet, so it's possible he's running this elsewhere.  I would advise not to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Variable *count* can be anywhere on the scope chain, see other answers. It was global in the OP, you didn't change it, so that's where it is for now (though it should be removed as a formal parameter in the declaration of *fnShowMarquee*).

Comment: -1 don't pass strings to setTimeout, it is eval in disguise and eval is evil.

Comment: @QmunkE: Can you provide an alternative? I'd gladly implement it.

Comment: @Blender the correct way to use setTimeout is to pass a function as the first argument (as shown in the answer by @JamesKhoury). The OP's code can be "fixed" by changing the setTimeout to be setTimeout(function() { fnShowMarquee(count); }, 4000);

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are using a global `count` then creating a new local in `fnShowMarquee`

Try this instead:

```
var count = 0;

//...

function fnShowMarquee(){  
    //...
    setTimeout (fnShowMarquee, 4000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fnShowMarquee();
});
```

**EDIT:-** From RobG's comment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    //...

    function fnShowMarquee(){ ... }
    fnShowMarquee();
});
```

by putting it all in the ready function the count variable cannot be accessed by other code and it will not mess around in the `window` global scope.

Comment: Yes, but better to hold *count* in a closure so it isn't global and able to be messed around by other code.

Comment: @RobG Thats right! It will still be global the the closure scope and won't affect outside code. Or it can be moved into the ready function.

Answer (score 2):

Further to James' answer, keep *count* and *marqueeText* in closures so they can't be messed around by other code:

```
var fnShowMarquee = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    var marqueeText = [
       "Some text goes here",
       "A bit more verbose text goes here.",
       "Some more verbose <a href='xxx'>text</a>" + 
       " goes <a href='xxx'>here</a> with some <a href='xxx'>links</a>."
    ];
    // ...                           

    return function() {  
        //...
        setTimeout (fnShowMarquee, 4000);
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Made a few changes to your code:

1. You are using a global count variable. You don't need to pass it in
   the parameters.
2. The if condition should be count ==
   marqueeText.length - 1. In your previous code, marqueeText[count]
   was going off the bounds.
3. $('#marquee_box span') wasn't working for
   me. So I changed it to $('span#marquee_box')

Your code should be:

```
var count = 0;
var marqueeText = new Array("Some text goes here",
                            "A bit more verbose text goes here.",
                            "Some more verbose <a href='xxx'>text</a> goes <a href='xxx'>here</a> with some <a href='xxx'>links</a>."
                            );

function fnShowMarquee(){  
  console.log(count + "-" + marqueeText.length );
  if (count == marqueeText.length - 1){
      count = 0;      
  }
  else{           
      count++;
  }
  $('span#marquee_box').html(marqueeText[count]);

      // do some stuff, then wait 4 seconds and call function again

  setTimeout ("fnShowMarquee()", 4000);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    fnShowMarquee();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the parameter variable count. Not the global one. And the setTimeout like that uses the global one, because it runs your function on document scope.

Try to call your function as just

```
function fnShowMarquee()
```

or do it like

```
setTimeout (function() { fnShowMarquee(count); }, 4000);
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to setTimeout, pass functions instead.